# Edit dhcpd.conf file using one line shell command

Tags: bash, shell

I am looking one line shell command to edit `dhcpd.conf` lease time. I want to edit `default-lease-time` and  `max-lease-time` to subnet ip `172.16.31.0`. Any help is much appreciated.

Sample conf file:

```
subnet 172.16.31.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    # default gateway
    option routers 172.16.31.10;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;

    option domain-name "aaaaaa";
    option domain-name-servers 172.16.31.10;
    #option nis-domain "domain.org";

    range dynamic-bootp 172.16.31.80 172.16.31.90;
    default-lease-time 21600;
    max-lease-time 43200;

    host test {
        hardware ethernet 00:23:8b:42:3f:d1;
        fixed-address 172.16.31.3;
    }

}
subnet 172.16.31.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    # default gateway
    option routers 172.16.31.11;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;

    option domain-name "aaaaaa";
    option domain-name-servers 172.16.31.11;
    #option nis-domain "domain.org";

    range dynamic-bootp 172.16.31.80 172.16.31.90;
    default-lease-time 21600;
    max-lease-time 43200;

    host test {
        hardware ethernet 00:23:8b:42:3f:d8;
        fixed-address 172.16.31.4;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
[bash] # cat file
subnet 172.16.31.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    ...
    default-lease-time 21600;
    max-lease-time 43200;
    ...
}
subnet 172.16.31.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    ...
}
[bash] # sed -e '/^subnet 172.16.31.0 netmask/,/^}/{' \
             -e '  s/^\( *default-lease-time\).*/\1 new-default;/' \
             -e '  s/^\( *max-lease-time\).*/\1 new-max;/' \
             -e '}' file
subnet 172.16.31.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    ...
    default-lease-time new-default;
    max-lease-time new-max;
    ...
}
subnet 172.16.31.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    ...
}
[bash] #
```

Comment: @sexpect_Expect_for.Shells Thanks, it worked for me!